# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0 mstest crashes nunit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, nunit, mstest

I have NUnit and MsTest in one project. Solution is common for whole team and only I have crash. Building solution works well, no errors. While running NUnit test I get exception: `IO exception cannot load Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0.`

I have one way reference, UnitTest project has reference to main Web project.
To write new tests I can use only MsTest but I would like NUnit.

I tried:

1. removing this dll -> but it crashes msTest (I want to have both
   franeworks)
2. Upgrading dll but it makes another error (mayby I
   could drill deeper this idea)
3. run as Administrator
4. In tests, Set default
   process architecture x64 or x86
5. upgrading NUnit, NUnit Adapter ->
   makes errors, solution is a bit old and I cannot actually upgrade so
   much.

It seems Solution while testing only NUnit, tries to use MsTest dll, problem occures only for me in team. I've downloaded Repo recently compare to my team. Mayby I have someting newer than others and it's incompatible? I have VS2017. However others have VS2017 too.

I am stuck, please help

Comment: Try using the fusion log viewer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer. Set it up to trace bind failures and see which version of the file it is trying to load. That might give you a clue what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Solved after seting 'Copy Local' =  true